# Turn multiple lines of code into comments in Jupyter Notebook on Mac and Spanish ISO

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How do I turn my code into comments in Jupyter Notebook? There are many threads saying that `ctrl` + `/` does this, but this doesn't do anything for me.

I am using a Macbook from Latin America. It's running Mac OS High Sierra. My keyboard setup is `Spanish ISO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `ctrl` + `/` only works on US keyboards.

This is done with `ctrl` + `-` on Mac OS and Spanish ISO.

Just highlight the code and use the keyboard shortcut to turn multiple lines of code to comments.

Comment: `ctrl` + `-` doesn't do anything for me. `cmd` + `-` reduces the zoom level. Is there another shortcut? Can that shortcut be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Select all the text you want to comment and press single quotes (') 3 times.

'''   code   '''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).